# java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class that attempts to sub-class erroneous class

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

While applying proguard to application m getting following verify error, I have seen other variants of verify errors but the following seems bit different,
Proguard version: 5.3.3,
Following MainApplication class extends android.app.Application and crash occurs at super.onCreate(); of onCreate() method

and in my proguard m having

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgent
```

,also I have mentioned

-dontshrink
-dontoptimize

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapplication, PID: 18598
    java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class com.myapplication.MainApplication that attempts to sub-type erroneous class ak (declaration of 'com.myapplication.MainApplication' appears in /data/app/com.myapplication-v4oPXfQv5kNLX1oUA9GwUw==/base.apk)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1102)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:983)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5715)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class ak that attempts to sub-type erroneous class en (declaration of 'ak' appears in /data/app/com.myapplication-v4oPXfQv5kNLX1oUA9GwUw==/base.apk)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1102) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:983) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5715) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
     Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class en: void en.<init>(android.content.Context) failed to verify: void en.<init>(android.content.Context): [0xA] thrown class Precise Reference: bjp not instanceof ThrowableVerifier rejected class en: void en.attachBaseContext(android.content.Context) failed to verify: void en.attachBaseContext(android.content.Context): [0x7] thrown class Precise Reference: bjp not instanceof Throwable
```

With analyze apk I can see following is not obfuscated without proguard

```
.class public Lcom/myapplication/MainApplication;
.super Landroid/app/Application;
.source "MainApplication.java"
```

but same was obfuscated once I apply proguard,

```
.class public Lcom/myapplication/MainApplication;
.super Lak;
.source "SourceFile"
```

correct me if m wrong,
 with following

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
```

it must not obfuscate application classes, why does above happen..?

Comment: I have been using proguard for so long for above application and never faced any  issues like this, this all happens after updating Gradle plugin version to 3.1.3

Comment: try to add option `-verbose` and then paste the console output (in case you shouldn't be able to figure out what it is trying to tell you there). that one rule you have there should keep the class, to be referenced in the `Manifest.xml`. see the `mapping.txt` once, what exactly that `erroneous class ec` is.

Comment: @MartinZeitler from mapping file i can see android.app.application is mapped to android.app.Application -> ak:
    20:20:void <init>() -> <init> and class "en" mapped to
android.content.ContextWrapper -> en:

Comment: @MartinZeitler m not sure why android default classes get obfuscated including android.os.Environment, android.os.Handler

Comment: now started getting NoSuchmethod error for java/lang/stringbuilder
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method a(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder; in class Ljava/lang/StringBuilder; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.StringBuilder' appears in /system/framework/core-oj.jar)

Answer (score 3):

I had the exactly same error after resolving a lot of conflicts and rebases. I just cleaned the project and rebuilt it. It was working again like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the [ContextWrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper) ...it is being stated, that:

> **Known direct subclasses**
>
> Application, BackupAgent, ContextThemeWrapper, IsolatedContext, MutableContextWrapper, RenamingDelegatingContext, Service

... of which not all are declared in your ProGuard `-keep` configuration.

you would need to add a rule alike the one below, which is a different approach, than adding all the individual sub-classes explicitly by their name... the `public` keyword is rather optional there, because those `private`/`protected` methods do not really need to be obfuscated, simply because the SDK sources package is publicly available for download. adding the `-verbose` switch into the configuration always makes ProGuard complain about "what to do", always with a hyperlink to the user manual.

```
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContextWrapper {public *;}
```

uploading `mapping.txt` to Crashlytics helps, when dealing with crashes in obfuscated builds.

Comment: sure will try above

Comment: fixed issues with above and i have noticed some new issues, with mapping.txt i can see native Android gets obfuscated including android.os.Environment,Handler and native java classesjava.lang.StringBuilder,
m not sure why above classes obfuscated

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my application didn't have a transitive dependency that was present in a library. After adding this dependency to the Gradle build script, everything is working fine.